# problem with tilde in .launch file in kinetic ros

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello it seems like when i give an argument inside a .launch file and it contains a tilde character this character is not recognized properly and does not get converted to /home/username/.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316174/problem-with-tilde-in-.launch-file-in-kinetic-ros/) by [arminkazim7](https://answers.ros.org/users/40117/arminkazim7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> a tilde character this character is not recognized properly and does not get converted to /home/username/.

the problem is that you're assuming this is a generic bit of functionality or behaviour ("in Linux"), but it's actually `bash` that substitutes `/home/username` for things like `~` and `$HOME`.

`roslaunch` does not do this, or at least not in the way you're currently using it.

You *could* consider using the `env` [substitution arg](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args) for this specific case (with `$HOME`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arminkazim7](https://answers.ros.org/users/40117/arminkazim7/) on 2019-02-20**:
Thanks a lot for your answer i got that point. So here is the solution  <...args="$(env HOME)..." />

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-20**:
It should not be necessary to set `HOME` yourself.

In fact, from the documentation on `env`:

> NOTE: Values set using the `<env>` tag will not be seen by `$(env ...)`